# change anchor tag value via css

Tags: html, css

I have this code in html:

```
<li id="media-personal-li" class="current selected"><a id="user-media" href="#">Media <span>0</span></a></li>
```

via css, I am trying to change where it says `Media`

I have tried this so far:

```
#media-personal-li a#user-media::before {
    content: "My Media";
    display: inline;
}
```

but what happens is it just adds `My Media` instead of replacing Media. Please see the tested code below:

```css
#media-personal-li a#user-media::before {
    content: "My Media";
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<li id="media-personal-li" class="current selected"><a id="user-media" href="#">Media <span>0</span></a></li>
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Could someone please share their ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can't replace content with css, you need JavaScript for that

Comment: But I can hide it, then I just can't figure out how to add to it after it's been hidden. So you're saying that even that way it's not possible?

Comment: You may be able to omit "Media" then use `::before` with various other selectors to set `content: "Media"` or `content: "My Media"` based on the other selectors.

Comment: @StephenP right so I believe I did try that actually. I did `#media-personal-li a#user-media{ display: none }, and then tried to add the new css in there, and put !important at the end, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Yes, because when you `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` the `::before` and/or `::after` is also none/hidden. I think there really isn't enough information in the question to answer with a solution... for example - why don't you just set the text to "My Media" in the first place? Under what _conditions_ should it change?

Comment: Yeah I failed to mention the reason is because the site is build via Wordpress, and I can't access the php file which holds the heading. I am easily, or so I thought, able to change it via adding additional css. I guess I should dig harder to find it the php file and just change it manually

Comment: You _could_ change your `content: "My Media"` to just `content: "My "` — but beware what itsallgoodie says in their answer: the "My" won't be seen by a screen reader.

Comment: Yep that could be a decent stopgap solution

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. CSS can't replace the HTML content of an element. By using the `::before` selector you can add a pseudo element to the page but its generally bad practice to use it for content as screen readers don't always pick up on it.

If you have an accessible usecase where you'd want your anchor tag to display the word "Media" to screen readers and something else ivisually you could add a `<span>` into your anchor tag and then visually hide it.

```css
#media-personal-li a#user-media::before {
  content: "My Media";
  display: inline;
}

.visually-hidden {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<li id="media-personal-li" class="current selected"><a id="user-media" href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Media <span>0</span></span></a></li>
```

As noted in the comments above, if you want to truly replace content on the page, you'd need to use JS instead of CSS.

Comment: this is a great solution. I wish I could use it. Not your fault, it's mine. I failed to mention the reason is because the site is build via Wordpress, and I can't access the php file which holds the heading. I am easily, or so I thought, able to change it via adding additional css. I guess I should dig harder to find it the php file and just change it manually

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing is almost correct. You just need to put your original text in `span` with some classname. Hide that `original-text span` if its under `#user-media`.

See the Snippet below, I have created 2 example. One with `user-media` another with different id.

```css
#media-personal-li a#user-media::before {
    content: "My Media ";
    display: inline;
}
#media-personal-li a#user-media span.original-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="media-personal-li" class="current selected"><a id="user-media" href="#"><span class="original-text">Media </span><span>0</span></a></li>
<li id="media-personal-li" class="current selected"><a id="user-text" href="#"><span class="original-text">Text </span><span>1</span></a></li>
```